# How to remove a stripped/broken sparkplug on a 2001 Chevy Malibu

Tags: sparkplugs, chevrolet, malibu

I have tried to remove the #3 spark plug from my 2001 Malibu, with no results. It is very hard to get to that particular spark plug because there is not much room between the fire wall and cylinder. I somehow broke the top off and the bottom of the spark plug is cracked in half. I tried different tools but still won't come out. There is not enough clearance in the area of the #3 spark plug to fit a drill in there or any other kind of tool. Please help, it's the only car I have, plus I have no money and I know just a enough about cars, to keep mine from going to an auto-repar shop. I was trying to change the plugs for a smog check, which is now past due.

Comment: I take it from your statement, the threads of the spark plug have broke off and are still in the head? If so, did the rest of the spark plug come out (porcelain and electrode)? If this is the case, you should be able to use the correct size "easy-out" removal tool to back it out. If this is not the case, please explain it better so we can understand. Getting to the #3 is a PITB, but can be done. I had this one strip out on me on a 94 Sunbird ... took 4-5 hours or so to re-thread and helicoil without removing the head (or anything else for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a right angle adapter in your drill to give you more room.
Here is a link to the sort of thing  http://www.screwfix.com/p/angled-drill-chuck-10mm/39590

You could then try the easy out or if that fails [or it snaps off] weld an old ring spanner over the stub of the spark plug, the heat from the weld will help to free the plug. You can place a long tube over the ring spanner to get more leverage so be sure to position it optimally when you weld it on, as it may be the last chance you have to free it.

Answer (score 1):

For stuck plugs use "SeaFoam" brand penetrating oil.  It is the best.  You may have to let it sit and work for a few days though. I have not seen this engine but it sounds like a tight spot so use a universal off the socket. Also use a 12 sided socket and, to make sure it doesn't skip, lightly grease the inside of the socket and dip it in sand blasting sand then gently tap the socket into place.  A socket treated this way will give tight, positive grip and  with luck, and a 4 foot snipe, the plug should come out.  Worked for me anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the body of plug is still screwed into head squirt wd40 liberally and leave
o/night.You can then purchase a thin straight wall plug socket much like you would
use on a lawnmower (the type you put a screwdriver through to turn)This should easily fit in gap surrounding plug

Answer (score 0):

If there is no room for drill I would try to do as written in this [guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_2086875_remove-spark-plugs-top-has.html). It seems that this could be a cheap solution for your problem. EZout extractor can be bought on ebay or maybe at your local house tools store. I hope it helps.